# What checksum is Super Smash Bros. Wii U using?

Tags: hash-functions

When you save a screenshot in *Super Smash Bros.* for Wii U on the SD card it writes to, it makes two files: a `.JPG` and a `.BIN` file. Both these files are in the format of `HNI_XXXX.EXTENTION`, where *XXXX* is the number of the screenshot. I believe that the `.BIN` file is (at least in part) a checksum to verify that the images are not edited (outside of the game), because modifying the `.JPG` file in any way will cause the game to refuse to recognize it.

Since the `.BIN` file is always 32-bytes exactly, I've tried using some of the common 265-bit checksums like SHA-256, and GOST. But none have ever matched up what has been contained in the `.BIN` files.

I've included three sets of images and their respective checksums in a [convenient zip file](http://www.speedyshare.com/tuyB3/snapshots.zip), so please take a look.

Does anyone have any ideas what checksum *Super Smash Bros.* might be using? If you need any more details I'd be more than happy to provide them.

Comment: The sha-256 checksums of the image does not match with the ones you provided. Perhaps you may like to upload the images to a service which does not alter them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because this is not a question about reverse engineering. If the only two datapoints are a data file and a digest, then there's nothing to reverse engineer. If you'd like to share the code for the software that generates the digest, then feel free to re-open this question.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders Sorry about that. I've added a link to download a zip file containing them all. Hopefully they didn't get messed up this time. :)